# Design of a simple user preference object in java?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I want to design a simple user preference object and its hierarchy. It should be something like

```
preference
   String Name
   Object Value

booleanPreference
   String Name
   Boolean Value
```

....

It goes on like that. The preference type changes from class to class. How would I go about implementing such a simple design "abstract class/interface/"?

Comment: Is your question about finding a design pattern or are you looking for a solution and don't mind to use a library for that? Then you might wanna have a look at [commons-configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with an interface:

```
public interface Preference<T>  {
    String getName();
    T getValue();
}
```

Implementation might look like this (not sure about generic; didn't compile to check):

```
public class PreferenceImpl implements Preference<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final T value;

    public PreferenceImpl(String name, T value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public T getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

Comment: There is not much in the object that requires to be an abstract class so defining behaviour and using interface seems a better idea. Also I have totally spaced out generics. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: But that's what I did.  There's no abstract class here.  And generics are key because you don't want to create a new implementation for each and every class you want to use with Preference.

Comment: I agree with you. Did not mean to sound the other way. I like the simplicity of it.